# use a relative pronoun inside of another one

Tags: relative-clauses

I would like to know whether one can use a relative pronoun inside of another one. For instance,

> I should finish my homework before 5 pm when I would like to watch a movie, which is a Nolan's movie.

Comment: What do you mean by _a relative pronoun inside of another one_? As far as I can see, there's only one relative pronoun in your sentence: _which_, which starts the relative clause _which is a Nolan's movie._ And why don't you opt instead for the neater and tighter version of this sentence: _I should finish my homework before 5 pm,  when I would like to watch a Nolan movie?_

Comment: I conisder when as a relative pronoun. I meant when is a relative pronoun and I used which inside of the sentence that when is.

Comment: I suspected that, but _when_ in yout sentence is a _conjunction_ (and not a _relative pronoun._)

Comment: @user405662 I'd classify "when" is a preposition, in accordance with modern grammar. The meaning can be glossed as "at which time"

Comment: @BillJ: So the grammar of a sentence changes completely when you change the wording from "the day when I discovered the secret cupboard in my house" to "the day that I discovered the secret cupboard in my house"? I don't understand "modern grammar".

Comment: @Peter Shor The _when_ version (_relative adverb_) emphasizes _the act of discovering_, while the _that version_ (_reduced relative clause where the relative pronoun **that**   is optional_) lays emphasizes on _the day._ Even traditional grammar would deal differently with them, right?—

Comment: @User40475 I would consider **when** as a conjunction if it specifies the time at which something happens: "We will go home when you have finished". In this sentence, the time at which something happens is specified by the prepositional phrase "before 5pm": **when** is a relative pronoun that introduces a non-defining relative clause "when I would like to watch a movie": it simply provides additional information, and does not specify the time..

Comment: @User40475: yes, traditional grammar also deals with these differently, which might be a good reason for replacing it by "modern grammar" if you could just figure out the correct "modern grammar". To me, the words "that" and "when" seem like they're playing exactly the same role in those sentences.

Comment: I should finish my homework before 5 pm, when I would like to watch a Nolan movie? This sentence is nearly as bad as the original Why would you use "when" in a sentence like this one? "I should finish my homework before 5 pm, **at which time** I would like to watch a Nolan movie? You would use a conjunction such as **because** not when! When would be used in a case like this** I should finish my homework before 5 pm, when the Nolan's movie will start.**

Comment: @PeterShor  "the day when I discovered the secret cupboard in my house __" and "the day that I discovered the secret cupboard in my house __" the grammar doesn't change, both are same. *when* is a preposition and *that* is a subordinator. In both cases the antecedent is the temporal adjunct - *"the day"*. The only difference is that in case of subordinator the gap is related directly but in case of the preposition the gap is related indirectly through *when*.

Comment: 'I should finish my homework before 5 pm when I would like to watch a movie, which is a Nolan's movie' sounds unnatural.  'I should finish my homework before 5 pm, when I would like to watch a Nolans movie' is unmarked, while 'I should finish my homework before 5 pm, when I would like to watch a movie – a Nolans movie' adds emphasis or shows an afterthought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the comments and the answers, people are getting hung up on whether *when* is a conjunction or a relative pronoun or a preposition.  For the answer to this question, it doesn't matter. Grammatically, you can nest these phrases as much as you want. Consider the nursery rhyme *The House that Jack Built*, whose sixth verse is:

> This is the cow with the crumpled horn,
> That tossed the dog,
> That worried the cat,
> That killed the rat,
> That ate the malt
> That lay in the house that Jack built.

which has six relative clauses, each inside the previous one. It's grammatical.

And consider this question in [elu.stackexchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137290/relative-clause-inside-another-relative-clause#:%7E:text=There%20is%20no%20grammatical%20rule,long%20sentence%20of%20Cicero%20knows.), that asks "Is it ok to have a relative clause inside another relative clause?" The answer says "yes".

If you stack more than three or so relative clauses inside each other, it might be confusing, and some people will consider it bad style, but it's still grammatical.

Answer (score 0):

**A relative pronoun is a word** that introduces a dependent (or relative) clause and connects it to an independent clause. Therefore I think you are a little confused between pronouns and clauses. Please use the link below.

Ref [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/relative-pronouns/)

> I should finish my homework before 5 pm when I would like to watch a movie, which is a Nolan's movie.

Why would you want to write something in this way? Try this;

> I should finish my homework before 5 pm **because** *I would like to watch a Nolan's movie.*

---

**Please note we are using a conjunction not a relative pronoun.**
A conjunction is a word which is used to link thoughts and ideas within a sentence. Ref [What is a Conjunction?](https://7esl.com/english-conjunctions/)

**because**; conjunction; for the reason that: Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/because)

> In fact *because is a subordinating conjunction* it can be used to join dependent and independent clauses. This type of conjunction can be used as a way of showing case and effect relationships between two clauses or a contrast, as well as various other relationships which might occur.